# How do you specify pandas groupby and aggregate operations that operate on other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe as follow:

```
+----+-------+-------+
| id | col_1 | col_2 |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 | 1.2   |     0 |
|  1 | 7.2   |     0 |
|  1 | 12.1  |     1 |
|  1 | 15.2  |     0 |
|  1 | 16.3  |     1 |
|  1 | 21.1  |     0 |
|  1 | 22.2  |     0 |
|  2 | 3     |     0 |
|  2 | 5     |     1 |
+----+-------+-------+
```

How can I create a new column (col_3) using col_1 and col_2 for each id where for each element I in col_1 if exists an element J in col_1 where

1) I < J <= I + 10 and
2) corresplonding element of J in col_2 is 1
col_3 is 1 otherwise 0?

For example, col_3 for above dataframe would be:

```
+----+-------+-------+-------+
| id | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 | 1.2   |     0 |     0 |
|  1 | 7.2   |     0 |     1 |
|  1 | 12.1  |     1 |     1 |
|  1 | 15.2  |     0 |     1 |
|  1 | 16.3  |     1 |     0 |
|  1 | 21.1  |     0 |     0 |
|  1 | 22.2  |     0 |     0 |
|  2 | 3     |     0 |     1 |
|  2 | 5     |     1 |     0 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am use numpy method

```
l=[]
for _,x in df.groupby('id'):
    s=(((x['col_1'].values > x['col_1'].values[:, None]) &(x['col_1'].values <= (x['col_1'].values[:, None] + 10))) & x['col_2'].values.astype(bool)).any(1).astype(int).tolist()
    l.extend(s)


df['col_3']=l
df
Out[400]: 
   id  col_1  col_2  col_3
0   1    1.2      0      0
1   1    7.2      0      1
2   1   12.1      1      1
3   1   15.2      0      1
4   1   16.3      1      0
5   1   21.1      0      0
6   1   22.2      0      0
7   2    3.0      0      1
8   2    5.0      1      0
```

Comment: Wen approach is much faster than Haleemur!

Comment: @Soroosh aha, thank for the information , happy coding

Answer (score 1):

let `f` be a function used to filter the data frame where `i` is a value from `col_1`

```
def f(i): 
    return (df.col_2 == 1) \
         & (df.col_1 <= i + 10) \
         & (df.col_1 > i)

df['col_3'] = df.apply(lambda x: ((df.id==x.id) & f(x.col_1)).any(), axis=1).astype(int)
```

prouduces output:

```
   id  col_1  col_2  col_3
0   1    1.2      0      0
1   1    7.2      0      1
2   1   12.1      1      1
3   1   15.2      0      1
4   1   16.3      1      0
5   1   21.1      0      0
6   1   22.2      0      0
7   2    3.0      0      1
8   2    5.0      1      0
```